# Representing Business process in Excel

Tags: excel, bpmn

I am looking for a way to take input of Business Processes in Excel.

The processes can be complex for example

[image]

I have seen couple of representations like,

https://fedcsis.org/proceedings/2016/pliks/376.pdf

But most of them are not friendly for a non technical user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really know if you are on the correct site for that type of question!

Comment: For that type of image you could use the drawing tools of Excel or (better) Ms Visio if you have it. There are also several tools for drawing schemas, maybe Excel is the worst one.

Comment: What do you mean by *take input*? You want to draw, implement, execute business processes in Excel?

Comment: As I mentioned in second part of question, I am looking at all options to represent the process. I was thinking of a representation which would be easily representative for a non technical person.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Excel. By default, a blank worksheet opens. Select the "Page Layout" tab, click "Orientation" in the Page Setup group and choose "Landscape."
2. Select the "Insert" tab. Click "SmartArt" in the Illustrations group to open the Choose a SmartArt Graphic dialog.
3. Choose "Process" in the list of chart types. Select the process chart subtype that best suits your needs, such as "Step Down Process" or "Gear" to preview it and read a description. Click "OK" to select the graphic with which you want to begin.
4. Add text to the first step in the process. Click on the sample text and type the text you want displayed directly over it. Type the desired text onto each shape.
5. Add an additional shape for each step in your business process. Click on a shape that will connect to the new shape and select the "Design" tab under SmartArt Tools. Click the "Add Shape" drop-down arrow in the Create Graphic section and choose where you want to add a new shape, such as before, after, above or below the current shape.
6. Customize the appearance of the flow chart. Click anywhere within the flow chart to select it and select the "Design" tab under SmartArt Tools. Click the "Change Colors" button in the SmartArt Tools section and click on the color scheme you want to apply. Click the SmartArt Styles drop-down arrow and select a 3-D or other style.
7. Click the "Save" button on the Quick Access toolbar or press "Ctrl-S" to save the completed business process flow chart before closing the worksheet.

Hope to useful..